# How to extract information from nested arrays with multiple objects?? (AdminReport.Activities.list)

Tags: arrays, object, properties, nested

Could anyone point me in the correct direction?
I searched plenty... I had no luck with mapping... or "find" nor extracting the data I need.

My code:

```
function checkMeetCode(meetCode, index, searchDate) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('AsistenciaMeet');
  var colB = ss.getRange("D3:D").getValues(); 
  var filasLlenasLengthB = colB.filter(String).length; // 

  var userKey = 'all';
  var applicationName = 'meet';
  var emailAddress = colB[index];
                               Logger.log("Index / Alumno: "+index+" / " + emailAddress);
  var optionalArgs = {
      event_name: "call_ended",
      endTime: searchDate,   
      startTime: fechaRestada(searchDate),
      filters: "identifier==" + emailAddress + ",meeting_code==" + meetCode 
    };

      var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs)
      Logger.log("RESPONSE: "+response);

      var actividad = response.items;

      if (actividad == null) {
         // do nothing
      }
      else {

        **// HERE IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO FIND / EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM "response"
        // READ BELOW PLEASE.**
      }

}
```

NEED HELP WITH: 
I want to FIND/EXTRACT the intValue of **"duration_seconds"**:

The results from:

```
Logger.log("RESPONSE: "+response);
```

RESPONSE: {"kind":"admin#reports#activities","etag":"\"JDMC8884sebSctZ17CIssbQ/IhilrSKVziEhoZ7URUpQ-NrztHY\"","items":[{"events":[{"parameters":[{"name":"video_send_seconds","intValue":"1829"},{"name":"screencast_recv_packet_loss_mean","intValue":"0"},{"name":"identifier_type","value":"email_address"},{"name":"video_send_packet_loss_max","intValue":"0"},{"name":"endpoint_id","value":"meet_android_4154513448557872"},{"name":"video_recv_long_side_median_pixels","intValue":"320"},{"name":"calendar_event_id","value":"44jr4vu3qo75q6bvkknq_20200421T213000Z"},{"name":"video_send_fps_mean","intValue":"29"},{"name":"video_recv_short_side_median_pixels","intValue":"180"},{"name":"network_estimated_download_kbps_mean","intValue":"351"},**{"name":"duration_seconds","intValue":"1830"},**{"name":"video_send_bitrate_kbps_mean","intValue":"762"},{"name":"network_recv_jitter_msec_max","intValue":"130"},{"name":"ip_address","value":"186.59.21.55"},{"name":"audio_send_seconds","intValue":"1829"},{"name":"screencast_recv_packet_loss_max","intValue":"0"},{"name":"video_recv_seconds","intValue":"1818"},{"name":"network_rtt_msec_mean","intValue":"36"},{"name":"video_send_long_side_median_pixels","intValue":"640"},{"name":"screencast_recv_seconds","intValue":"1829"},{"name":"product_type","value":"meet"},{"name":"video_recv_packet_loss_max","intValue":"0"},{"name":"is_external","boolValue":false}],"name":"call_ended","type":"call"}] ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, after roughly 8 hours... I was able to make it work.

```
var insideParameters = response["items"][0]["events"][0]["parameters"];
Logger.log(insideParameters.length);

for (var i = 30; i<insideParameters.length;i++){ // its always located above i = 30...
  if(insideParameters[i].name === "duration_seconds"){
    var duration = insideParameters[i].intValue;
    Logger.log(duration);
  }   
}
```